# how to invoke System Command in an R function

Tags: r

I want to make an R script that invokes the system command.

The Linux command I want to use in the R script is:

```
plink --bfile myPlinkBinaryData --recode --out myPlinkTextData
```

So far this is what I have in my R file:

```
setwd("/Users/swirlydino/Desktop/OriginalData")
getwd()
system("plink --bfile OriginalData --recode --out myPlinkTextData")
```

However, I get this:

```
Web-based version check ( --noweb to skip )
Recent cached web-check found...Problem connecting to web

Writing this text to log file [ myPlinkTextData.log ]
Analysis started: Wed Sep  6 14:28:48 2017

Options in effect:
    --bfile OriginalData
    --recode
    --out myPlinkTextData


ERROR: No file [ OriginalData.fam ] exists.
```

When I run the command, plink --bfile OriginalData --recode --out myPlinkTextData, in Terminal it works and creates the two files I need. So how come it is not working in the R script?

Any help will be so grateful :)

Comment: Do you get an error? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: No, I don't. But I am not even sure that is the way to start...for what I want to happen, described above.

Comment: when you run `system("plink --bfile myPlinkBinaryData --recode --out myPlinkTextData")` directly in the R concole - what is the answer?  For me its `sh: 1: plink: not found` because I don't have the program on my computer.

Comment: thanks, i was not aware that I can run shell commands in R.

Comment: I have plink installed in my computer. When I run 'system("plink --bfile myPlinkBinaryData --recode --out myPlinkTextData")' I get: 'ERROR: No file [ OriginalData.fam ] exists.' However, when I do that command in terminal it works.

Comment: Try the absolute path or change your working directory

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I believe I have done that before running the system command code...right?

Comment: @swirlydino -- Did you manage to resolve the issue?